# How to proof this upper bound in a tree with limited degree

Tags: algorithm, tree, proof

Hope someone will know the answer.

Say I have a tree `T` with maximum degree **d >=2**.

Proof there exist an `egde e` such as by removing `e` from `T` you'll get two trees `T1` and `T2` that each one of them contains maximum

**⌈ |V|*(d-1)/d⌉** vertices.

Where `|V|` is the numbers of vertices in the tree `T`

Comment: Contains maximum `⌈ |V|*{(d-1)/d} ⌉`, vertexes?

Comment: `{ }` is a special operation I dont know? Or they are just like parenthesis?

Comment: Sooo you can''t help solving it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a mathematical challenge and thus is more suited for http://math.stackexchange.com